# Roblox - while testing trusses work when i drag them in, but when i use script to set all the stuff, then i cant climb it

Tags: roblox

I am using a script to set cancollide = true and transparency = 0, but i cant climb the truss. but when I'm already in testing mode (in studio) and i drag in the same truss, i can climb it, and i am looking at properties, its same, both anchored is true, they are touching same parts, i dont know why this is happening. Please help thanks :)by the way, i am making tycoon and this is script i am using:

```
wait(1)

amount = 0 -- cost of model


owner = script.Parent.Parent.Owner

local stun = false

pcall(script.Parent.Head.Touched:connect(function(hit)
if hit.Parent ~= nil then
player = game.Players:findFirstChild(hit.Parent.Name)
    if not stun and player ~= nil then
        if player.Name == owner.Value then
            if player:findFirstChild("leaderstats") ~= nil then
            stats = player:findFirstChild("leaderstats")
                if stats.Money.Value >= amount then
                stun = true
                stats.Money.Value = stats.Money.Value - amount
                script.Parent.ladder.CanCollide = true
                script.Parent.ladder.Transparency = (0)
                script.Parent.Head:Remove()
                wait(1)
                stun = false
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
end))
```

dont worry about other stuff, it works, its just this part that matters now:

```
script.Parent.ladder.CanCollide = true
                script.Parent.ladder.Transparency = (0)
                script.Parent.Head:Remove()
```

Please help :( this is the problem with the ladder using script not working and same dragged in from toolbox truss working, iv done this with many trusses and ladders and same result :(

Answer (score 0):

So, a error I noticed in your code, is that you erase your Character's Head, which would kill your character, or possibly throw a error if the .Touched event fires two times.

---

There are many efficency errors in this script, such as `.Transparency = (0)`, or doing `script.Parent.ladder` instead of using variables, but it really is no problem most of the times. Something you could try, is to use `Instance.new()` to create the ladder.If this game is FilteringEnabled on (Expermiental mode off), please note your script won't work as intended if it is a LocalScript, it will only work well on Server-Side (aka, a normal Script instead of a LocalScript)